# How to unhide an excel sheet through c# without using interop

Tags: c#, asp.net, excel

My server guy is not ready to install office

I have written the following code in my form. It works fine from my machine but when I upload on the net; it does not work. This requires the **interop dlls** but the server guy is not ready to install office on the server. can any one help me as I need to **unhide sheet from excel**.

using excel;

```
        Excel.Application excelApp = new Excel.Application();

        string myPath = @fileLocation;
        excelApp.Workbooks.Open(myPath, Missing.Value, Missing.Value,Missing.Value, Missing.Value,Missing.Value, Missing.Value,Missing.Value, Missing.Value,Missing.Value, Missing.Value,Missing.Value, Missing.Value);//,Missing.Value, Missing.Value);

        //Get the first sheet.
        Excel.Worksheet objSheet = (Excel.Worksheet)excelApp.ActiveWorkbook.Sheets["abc"];

        //Unhide the worksheet.
        objSheet.Visible = Excel.XlSheetVisibility.xlSheetVisible;
        //Save As the Excel file.
        excelApp.ActiveWorkbook.Save();
```

Comment: So, you want us to tell you how to run code that depends on Excel being installed *without Excel being installed*?

Comment: Is this ASP.NET? If so, then your server guy is right. Don't run Office on a server.

Comment: @HenkHolterman This is ASP.NET in C#. How to work without interop.

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi Yes Sir.

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi  Excel is not installed on the server; but i want to unhide a sheet and read contents and save it in sql. Pls help

Comment: A little googling turns up [this post](http://forums.asp.net/post/5247662.aspx). There are multiple libs available.

Answer (score 2):

Use Open XML SDK and set the `Sheet`'s `State` property to `SheetStateValues.Hidden`.

**Sheet.State property**

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/documentformat.openxml.spreadsheet.sheet.state.aspx

**Open XML SDK 2.5 for Microsoft Office**

http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=30425

Don't use office automation on a server.

[image]